# Firebase Python Admin: provider_id only returning "firebase" and not "google.com"

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-admin

Hope you guys are having a great day!

I have run into an issue with the Firebase Python Admin SDK.

**ISSUE:** I am using [user = auth.get_user("firebase-user-uid")] to return info on specific accounts, everything works until I try to get the account provider ID using [account_type = user.provider_id] the expected returned string would be "google.com" but I am getting "firebase" returned instead (this issue is happening to all users, no matter the provider).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you guys for your time!

**Edit:** My goal with getting the provider ID is to display the account sign in type to the user using flask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "top-level" `provider_id` of someone signed into Firebase Authentication is expected to be `"firebase"` because it is obtained from the Firebase ID token issued to the user.

Linked account providers, like Google, Facebook and so on are found under the [`provider_data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserRecord.provider_data) property of the [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#userrecord) object as a list of [`UserInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#userinfo) objects.

Comment: For anyone wondering this is the code to access the provider ID in "provider_data",  user.provider_data[0].provider_id